# Bootstrap full screen background image misbehaving

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Relatively new to bootstrap 3, and running into trouble with a fullscreen background image. Trying to get the background image to take up the whole screen below the nav bar. Instead, it just occupies the space behind my h1 and button.  Here's my code

**HTML:**

```
<header id="top" class="header">
    <div class="text-vertical-center">
        <h1>Summer's Here</h1>
        <a href="Services.html" class="btn btn-lg">Register</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .header {
        display: table;
        position:relative;
        background: url(../images/splash.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
    }
```

Would love some guidance! Probably made a noob error.

Comment: Well you applied it to `.header`, and that element is only as big as its content requires … if you want it to fill the whole screen, apply it to `body` or `html`.